# returning the 2nd letter in a string in a list and sorted the words by it. keep getting indexing range out of bound. Python

Tags: python, indexing

I am working on an assignment with the below requirements:

You will be sorting the following list by each element’s second letter, a to z. Create a function to use when sorting, called second_let. It will take a string as input and return the second letter of that string. Then sort the list, create a variable called sorted_by_second_let and assign the sorted list to it.

This is my code:

```
ex_lst = ['hi', 'how are you', 'bye', 'apple', 'zebra', 'dance']

def second_let(x):

    lst= []
    for wrd in x:
        lst.append(wrd[1])
    return lst

print(second_let(ex_lst))
print(sorted(second_let(ex_lst)))

sorted_by_second_let= sorted(ex_lst, key= second_let)
```

I keep getting this error:

> IndexError: string index out of range on line 7, which is the lst.append(wrd[1]). what am I doing wrong? how can I do it better?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ex_lst = ['hi', 'how are you', 'bye', 'apple', 'zebra', 'dance']

def second_let(x):
    return x[1]

sorted_by_second_let= sorted(ex_lst, key= second_let)
```

Answer (score 3):

When you write:

```
sorted_by_second_let= sorted(ex_lst, key=second_let)
```

This will pass each **word** to `second_let`. Then in the function each `wrd` will be a single character, which is obviously not what you want.

If you want to simply sort by the second letter, the `key` function just needs to return that second letter. For example:

```
ex_lst = ['hi', 'how are you', 'bye', 'apple', 'zebra', 'dance']

sorted(ex_lst, key=lambda x: x[1])
# ['dance', 'zebra', 'hi', 'how are you', 'apple', 'bye']
```

There `x` is a word and `x[1]` is the second letter. `sorted()` will take care of the rest.

Comment: If anyone doesn't prefer using `lambda` you can use `itemgetter` instead.

Comment: @MarkMeyer Thank you so much for your advise. Is there another way to do it without Lambda? my assignment requests that I avoid using lambda and instead create a function "second_let).

Comment: @MoutazGendia yes, a lambda is a just a function so you can make `second_let` simply take an `x` parameter like you are and  `return x[1]`

Comment: @MarkMeyer Thank you Mark, just for my understanding, doesn't x here resemble the list(ex_lst) and wrd the items (str) in the list, so if I index x, then I would be indexing the items in the list rather than items in the characters in the wrd (here the srting)?  I am a bit confused..

Answer (score 2):

It depends on how `sorted` works when it has a `key` parameter that takes a function as value:

```py
ex_lst = ['hi', 'how are you', 'bye', 'apple', 'zebra', 'dance']

def second_let(x):
    return x[1]

sorted_by_second_let = sorted(ex_lst, key=second_let)
```

The `sorted` function loops through each item of the list when it is used like this. That is why there is no need for a `for` loop.